# Opening files in VS Code in docker bash ubuntu

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to open a file inside docker bash (I am using ubuntu terminal btw) using the ff commands:

```
sudo docker container exec -it rubybox bash

mkdir rubyfiles

cd rubyfiles

touch Dockerfile
```

And now when I run:

```
code .
```

It's suppose to open the file in Visual Studio code but instead I got this error:

```
bash: code: command not found
```

Any idea what's the correct command or how to configure this in order to open a file inside docker or terminal after running `code .`?

Comment: since code is not installed in container. its your local program. so you can use docker volumes and manage the volume folder with code to crud files/folders...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a GUI app with Docker. You need to share your screen with it. 
See: https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110

What you could do is to share the local `PWD` with Docker and work from here:

```
docker run -d -v $PWD:/t -w /t rubybox
```